# Firebase script is blocked by AdBlock

Tags: javascript, firebase, adblock

I've just added Firebase script to my website `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>` and unfortunately it's blocked by extensions like AdBlock, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

- [Change your AdBlock rules](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet#exceptions) to allow `gstatic.com` or at least the Firebase SDK.
- Host the Firebase SDK in a different place that AdBlock doesn't block.

Comment: Where should I place Firebase SDK then?

Comment: You can host it either in your web app itself (just download the file and put it in the same folder as your other JavaScript). Or you can put it on any other CDN.